# The corresponding Model for an itemtype defined in items.xml did not generated after ant clean all in Hybris

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I have defined a new Itemtype in items.xml and I was expecting a corresponding Model to it, but I don't see the generated Model after doing ant clean all

Here is the itemtype defined.

```
    <itemtype code="ABCComponent" autocreate="true"
    generate="true" extends="SimpleCMSComponent"
    jaloclass="de.hybris.platform.bobs.jalo.cms.components.ABCComponent">
    <description>Its my first custom component</description>
    <attributes>

        <attribute type="java.lang.String"
            qualifier="valueDescriptionTittle">
            <description>Tittle to display for the component</description>
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true"
                optional="true" />
            <persistence type="property"></persistence>
        </attribute>

        <attribute type="Media"
            qualifier="valuePropositionImgDesktop">
            <description>The image which can be attached for desktop view to this value proposition component.</description>
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true"
                optional="true" />
            <persistence type="property" />
        </attribute>

    </attributes>
```

Could anyone please let me know, where am getting wrong.

Comment: Are you getting any error? try refreshing platform extension in your IDE and check

Comment: I am not getting any exceptions and the build is also getting successful and i did the platform refresh also.

Comment: can you check if 'build.development.mode' is set to false by any chance in your set up.

Comment: Hi Vikranth, Yes i found that the build.development.mode was false in local.properties of config. But even after changing it to true and doing ant clean all and platform refresh, i still don't see the Model

Comment: I see some missing extensions in the Problems tab, however the build is getting successful.

Comment: search the Model class using find command or maybe Total Commander. Maybe Intellij does not have all of the Hybris Modules

Comment: Is there any chance you declared the itemtype in a beans.xml? Is the items.xml you declared your type in part of an extension that is declared in localextensions.xml? Please share the full path of the items.xml and the content of your localextensions.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Use your custom package name (jalo class) for new item or not set it, system auto assign package name.

Answer (score 0):

try (for items you need initialize):

```
ant clean all initialize
```